# How to Get and Output Field Choices in a Custom SharePoint List DispForm Page?

Tags: sharepoint, forms, xslt

I'm working on a custom Display Form for a SharePoint list. Is there a way to get the field choices for a field that has multiple choices? That is, I can print out the chosen value with something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Migration_x0020_Status" />
```

But, I want to print out all the choices, including the one that was chosen. The closest I've come is to use the FormField element from the EditForm page like the following:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Migration_x0020_Status" />
```

However, that prints out SELECT and OPTION elements. I want to get the underlying choices and print out my own stuff (eg: with UL and LI elements). How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest to use object model to create a custom webpart for the same. if thats not the CHOICE I would like to suggest a slight change in your architecture to include lookup column and then in your xslt datasource add the master list data source as well and then work on xslt to show it the way you want